# Bounds for perturbed polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Consider the univariate polynomial $$f(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_{1}x + a_{0}$$

Let $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_n)$ be an ordered list of zeros for $f$.  Assume that we have a polynomial $g(x) = \epsilon x^i$ where $0 \leq i \leq n$.  Let $(\hat{\lambda_1},\hat{\lambda_2},...,\hat{\lambda_n})$ be the ordered list of zeros of $f+g$.

Can we place a bound on $E = \max_j |\lambda_j-\hat{\lambda_j}|$ as a function of $\epsilon, a_n, a_{n-1}, ..., a_{0}$?

This question seems related to the [Wilkinson Polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson's_polynomial) where Wilkinson shows that small changes to polynomial coefficients can have large effects on its zeros.  However, Wilkinson didn't derive a bound for this result.

Comment: There is a result from complex analysis that tells you that if $|f|>|g|$ on the boundary of a region in the complex plane, then $f$ and $f+g$ have the same number of zeros (counted with multiplicity) within the region.

Comment: I figured out that your suggestion is referring to Rouche's Theorem, which seems somewhat relevant.  Unfortunately, the theorem only seems to place a one-sided bound on the largest $\lambda$, so it seems that additional reasoning is needed for a general two-sided bound on all $\lambda$.